# Compile D project with DMD

Tags: d, dmd

This might be stupidiest and newbie's question, but how do I actually compile D project with DMD on windows?

I tried these commands:

- `dmd *`
- `dmd *.d`
- `cd .. && dmd {DirectoryName}`
- `dmd file1.d file2.d`

But neither of them compile the project to executable.

I want to produce `.exe` file out of that project, but it seems I can't. I can only compile one file in the project or compile multiple, but only `.obj` file, not `.exe`...

Comment: It depends on the project... which one i it?

Comment: some use `dub build` though that would the next thing to try in general

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I am not using `dub` because `dub init` takes forever to make a project.

Comment: yeah i don't use dub either. But you are building your own project? I would probably just list the files, like your `dmd file1.d file2.d`... what happens when you try that?

Comment: Any errors when you execute `dmd file1.d file2.d` ?? Also you mentioned `cd .. && dmd {DirectoryName}` - are you using MSYS2 or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DUB](http://code.dlang.org/) is the easiest for beginners:

```
C:\Users\217216x715132\Desktop\tmp1>dub init
Package recipe format (sdl/json) [json]:
Name [tmp1]:
Description [A minimal D application.]:
Author name [217216X715132]:
License [proprietary]:
Copyright string [Copyright ┬⌐ 2019, 217216X715132]:
Add dependency (leave empty to skip) []:
Successfully created an empty project in 'C:\Users\217216x715132\Desktop\tmp1'.
Package successfully created in .

C:\Users\217216x715132\Desktop\tmp1>dub run
Performing "debug" build using dmd for x86.
tmp1 ~master: building configuration "application"...
Linking...
Running .\tmp1.exe
Edit source/app.d to start your project.

C:\Users\217216x715132\Desktop\tmp1>
```

You can copy all your d files to your-project\source\ directory and let dub do all the hard work.

`dub init` doesn't work from git bash for some reason, as it waits for input on CLI. So you need to `dub init` from cmd.exe. `dub run` should work fine from git bash.

If you run it from git bash, press enter key 7 times, all the defaults will be accepted and the project will be created.

```
arun MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tmp1$ dub init







Package recipe format (sdl/json) [json]: Name [tmp1]: Description [A minimal D application.]: Author name [217216X715132]: License [proprietary]: Copyright string [Copyright © 2019, 217216X715132]: Add dependency (leave empty to skip) []: Successfully created an empty project in 'C:\Users\217216x715132\Desktop\tmp1'.
Package successfully created in .

arun MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tmp1$
```

Related issue in [DUB](https://github.com/dlang/dub/issues/1682)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like Dub, you might try **[rdmd](https://dlang.org/rdmd.html)**, which comes with the standard D compiler.  E.g suppose you have a main.d file that imports other files:

```
rdmd --build-only main.d            # Build
rdmd --build-only -g -debug main.d  # Build in debug mode
rdmd main.d                         # Build temporary executable and run it
```

If you want to see the raw commands that dub executes to build your project, you can use:

```
dub build --force --verbose
```